# Issue with Wix not creating IIS pool before running SQL setup scripts

Tags: sql, iis, wix

I'm writing a Wix msi that needs to create a database, configure IIS and then run a few SQL setup scripts. The issue I'm running into is that the SQL scripts seem to be running before IIS has completed configuration with the appropriate pool / website. One of the SQL scripts relies on the IIS being configured and causes the installer to fail:

Here's what I have (Relevant parts pulled out of various *.wxs files):

Main.wxs:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SamplePortalApi.Setup" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="SamplePortalApiComponents" /> 
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyIISConfiguration" />
  <ComponentRef Id="SqlComponent" /> <!-- Database Setup / Scripts Run Here -->
</Feature>
```

ConfigureIIS.wxs:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Id="SamplePortalAppPool" Guid="" KeyPath="yes">
        <iis:WebAppPool Id="SamplePortalAppPool"
            Name="SamplePortalApi"
            Identity="applicationPoolIdentity"
            ManagedPipelineMode="Integrated" 
            ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
    </Component>

    <Component Id="InstallWebsite" Guid="" KeyPath="yes">       
        <iis:WebSite Id="SamplePortalApi" Description='SamplePortalApi' Directory='INSTALLFOLDER' AutoStart='no' StartOnInstall='no'>
          <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned" Port="[DB_PORT]" />
          <iis:WebApplication Id="SamplePortalApiApplication" Name="[SamplePortalApi][WEBSITE_ID]" WebAppPool="SamplePortalAppPool"></iis:WebApplication>
        </iis:WebSite>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <ComponentGroup Id="SamplePortalApiIisConfiguration">
      <ComponentRef Id="InstallWebsite" />
      <ComponentRef Id="SamplePortalAppPool" />
    </ComponentGroup>
```

Database.wxs

```
<Binary Id="MigrationBin" SourceFile="Migration.sql"></Binary>
<Binary Id="CreateLoginBin" SourceFile="CreateLogin.sql"></Binary>
<Binary Id="CreateUserBin" SourceFile="CreateUser.sql"></Binary>
<Binary Id="DeleteLoginBin" SourceFile="DeleteLogin.sql"></Binary>

<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="SqlComponent" Guid="8A1C82DB-1DD3-4FB5-8600-4F370FE1E04B">
    <Condition>NOT Installed</Condition>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SamplePortalApiDatabase" Database="[DB_DATABASE]" Server="[DB_SERVER]" CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" ContinueOnError="no">
      <sql:SqlScript Id="Migration" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="MigrationBin" ContinueOnError="no" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateLogin" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="CreateLoginBin"  ContinueOnError="no"/>      
      <sql:SqlScript Id="DeleteLogin" ExecuteOnInstall="no" ExecuteOnUninstall="yes" BinaryKey="DeleteLoginBin"  ContinueOnError="no"/>
    </sql:SqlDatabase>
    <CreateFolder/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

What's the best approach here? I think I could run the problematic SQL as a CustomAction rather than as part of the built in WXS functionality, but I don't think this is the most elegant approach. Is there a better way of ensuring that IIS is setup properly first?

Comment: Can I make sure that the SqlComponent ComponentRef only runs when the MyIISConfiguration ComponentGroup has 100% completed?

Comment: Did you get any error messages?

Comment: The error is a SQL error - one of the scripts relies on the IIS pools being in place. I can open up IIS and see it hasn't properly been created.

I've got round this whole thing by just calling the scripts separately in a CustomAction.